# Entity Framework Migrations not Detecting Model Change

Tags: entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to start using EF Migrations with an existing database.

The startup project is an MVC 3 project and the domain objects are in a separate project of the same solution.

Here are the steps I took:

> Add-Migration InitialMigration -IgnoreChanges -Verbose

Created Configuration.cs and ###_InitialMigration.cs.  Had to edit Configuration.cs to add the name of my context object as it is in a separate project.

> Update-Database

Added dbo.__MigrationHistory to my database

> Added a new property to an existing class

```
private ulong? myProp;
[DataMember]
public ulong? MyProp
{
    get { return myProp; }
    set
    {
        if (myProp != value)
        {
            myProp = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.MyProp);
        }
    }
}
```

Successfully compiled the solution.

> Add-Migration MyNewMigration

Created ###_MyNewMigration.cs, with no migrations in it:

```
public partial class MyNewMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

*Not looking good... where are the migrations?*

> Update-Database -Verbose -Script

*No mention of the new property in the upgrade script*

> INSERT INTO [__MigrationHistory] ([MigrationId], [CreatedOn], [Model], [ProductVersion])
>   VALUES ('201206122137444_MyNewMigration', '2012-06-12T22:07:49.170Z', 0x1F8B080YadaYada, '4.3.1')

How can I get EF Migrations to pick up the model change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that EF Migrations does not like the `ulong?` data type I used.  That property was ignored without any warning.

Changing the type to `long?` allowed the migration to succeed.